# How to resize the content loaded by jQuery's load method using CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using the load method to load a webpage with in my website.

```
// main.js
$(document).ready(function ()
{
    $("#content").html("<object data='http://tired.com/'>");
});

// index.html
<html>

<head>

    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/main.js"></script>

    <style type="text/css">

#container{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#content{
    margin-top: 10;
    margin-left: 100;
    margin-bottom: 10;
    margin-right: 10;

    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}

    </style>

</head>

<title>
Testing loading a html page into a div
</title>

<body>

    <div id="container">

        <div id="top">
            <p> Top </p>
        </div>

        <div id="content">
        </div>

        <div id="bottom">
            <p> Bottom </p>
        </div>

    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

In spite of giving the `content` div a height and width of 500px, the webpage still loads in it's original size.

How do I make it larger?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you setting #content as 500px wide or high?  I just see 90%, which will scale with your browser.  The % height setting may not work as you expect, either.

Comment: My apologies, I tried both. It still only loads in it's original size. I'll fix it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

It does work, check this fiddle.
[JSFiddle Demo Link](http://jsfiddle.net/tJCg6/)

You also might want to add `px` to your margins.

```
#content{
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    background:skyblue;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    padding:10px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend trying to set style on the object tag itself:

```
#content object {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```